# How to read a embedded image from xml file with xsl

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have a image embedded in a XML file (no the path, the image bits).

```
<image>Image pixels encoded in 64<image>
```

then my question is if it is possible make a transformation XSL to HTML over the xml file and show the image embedded.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's possible. And it's easy. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These days browsers have good support for `data` URLs so you can use e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="image">
  <img src="data:image/gif;base64,{.}"/>
</xsl:template>
```

if your XML `image` element(s) contain GIF image data. You need to adapt the MIME type obviously if you have PNG or JPEG images for instance.

Comment: Thanks, exactly that I want, now only I need to select based in a attribute by the type. Thanks again