# How to CONCAT "<" and ">" characters to build an img tag from postgresql via XML and XSL to HTML

Tags: html, xml, postgresql, xslt-1.0

I'm expanding an existing HTML report to add a row of images. All data comes from a PostgreSQL database with the query getting converted into XML, then it goes through an XSLT-1.0 transform to produce the final HTML output page.

The image data is stored in BYTEA form and is extracted as follows (in the SQL file):

```
SELECT string_agg(
    xmlelement(NAME "other_data", comes.from_here),
    xmlelement(NAME "more_data",  comes.from_here_too),
    xmlelement(NAME "image_file", CONCAT('<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG...', encode(rpaf.image_file, 'base64'), '"/>'))
)::TEXT
```

The XSL file does this with the data extracted...

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="12" class="table_data" align="left">
        <xsl:value-of select="image_file"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

However, the '<' and '>' characters are being replaced with `'&lt;'` and `'&gt;'` and this results in the HTML just outputting the raw text not the image (red dot image from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#HTML))...

```
<td colspan="12" class="table_data" align="left">&lt;img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="&gt;</td>
```

Where should I be adding the '<' and '>' characters, if not in the SQL? I've tried adding the characters in the XSL file but it doesn't work there either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer:**

You should not mix xml and string_agg. Also you should form your img as xmlelement, not as text value:

```sql
SELECT 
  xmlelement(NAME "table_data",
    xmlelement(NAME "other_data", comes.from_here),
    xmlelement(NAME "more_data",  comes.from_here_too),
    xmlelement(NAME "image_file", 
      xmlelement(NAME "img", XMLATTRIBUTES( CONCAT('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG...', encode(rpaf.image_file, 'base64')) as src )))
  )
FROM
  (VALUES('here', 'here-too')) comes(from_here , from_here_too),
  (VALUES('image'::bytea)) rpaf(image_file)
```

it returns:

```
<table_data>
  <other_data>here</other_data>
  <more_data>here-too</more_data>
  <image_file>
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG...aW1hZ2U="/>
  </image_file>
</table_data>
```

**My 2 cents:**

I think you are making a mistake trying to import a html `img` element into xsl template. Take a look at the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29191959/how-to-read-a-embedded-image-from-xml-file-with-xsl) to a problem similar to yours.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I'm kind of stuck using `string_agg()` as the query returns multiple rows and the output's concatenated into a long return string. I'm also currently trying to get to the bottom of how to expand the query so I can handle more than one picture per `image_file` tag

Comment: @fluffy_mart, I'm happy to help. The question was how not to get < and > characters encoded - thats what I was trying to solve using xmlelement to create "img". If you have a question about creating several img elements for "image_file" you should check XML  aggregate functions in PostgreSQL (namely xmlagg(xml)).

Comment: I saw that this was going to drift away from this question, so I created a new post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67179255/query-to-build-one-to-many-structure)